# Setting NSTableView cell text

Tags: macos, swift, nstableview

I have a NSTableView that I want to populate with 20 cells, each of them will say "Test". I'm fluent with UITableView's but not so much with NSTableViews, so I went hunting online to figure this out. Oh, how confused that made me! I understand that I need to use the `numberOfRowsInTableView` function, but how do I set the text of the cell? Each source I find seems to do everything in a different way. For instance, [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87002/getting-started-with-os-x-and-swift-tutorial-part-1) site uses:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> NSView! {
// 1
var cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn.identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView

// 2
if tableColumn.identifier == "BugColumn" {
  // 3
  let bugDoc = self.bugs[row]
  cellView.imageView!.image = bugDoc.thumbImage
  cellView.textField!.stringValue = bugDoc.data.title
  return cellView
}

return cellView
```

}

I tried that but I got an error - the code found nil while unwrapping an optional. Then I tried what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692177/cell-based-nstableview-behaves-incorrectly):

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, dataCellForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSCell? {
if tableColumn == nil { return nil }
if tableColumn!.identifier != "right" { return nil }
let cell = NSPopUpButtonCell()
cell.bordered = false
cell.menu!.addItemWithTitle("one", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
cell.menu!.addItemWithTitle("two", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
cell.menu!.addItemWithTitle("three", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
cell.selectItemAtIndex(1) // <--- obviously ignored ?!
return cell
```

}

So my question is, how do I set the cell text? How do the two examples I've inserted above differ in what they do? Please, make some sense of this - cause I sure can't!

-Thanks,
A confused CodeIt

P.S.
I've looked at several other sources except the two I named above. I'm just plain confused..

**Edit:**
The found nil while unwrapping an Optional error I mentioned in the first example is found on this line:

```
var cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn.identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView
```

Comment: which optional is found nil while unwrapping?

Comment: I get the error on the var cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn.identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView.

Comment: Are you making sure that 'tableColumn.identifier' exist ?

Comment: If by that you mean did I set an identifier for the table in the main.storyboard, then yes. The NSTableColumn has an Identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get an existing cell with the MyView identifier if it exists

var cellView?: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("someIdentifier", owner: self) as NSTableCellView

// There is no existing cell to reuse so create a new one

if cellView == nil {
    cellView = NSTableCellView(frame: NSRect())
// The identifier of the NSTextField instance is set to someIdentifier.
// This allows the cell to be reused.
     cellView.identifier = "someIdentifier
}
```

This should give you the cell, and you can proceed.
See [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html) for more